# Non inverting amplifier oscillations

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, filter, non-inverting

[image: Circuit]

[image: Output]

The point of this circuit is to take a 300 to 400 kHz 5Vpp square wave signal and convert in to a sinewave of the same frequency amplified with a gain of 2.

The filtering before the op amp seems to work and does the square to sine wave conversion well.

The circuit after the op amp is just to position the signal.

But for some reason, the op amp doesn't want to amplify the sinusoid signal properly. The opamp is LT1210.

Is there a reason for all the oscillations in the output of the op amp?

Comment: Did you read page 9 of the datasheet? There are two sections there related to possible oscillation.

Comment: Clean up the schematic.  Those dots make things hard to see.  Don't just dump screen shots on us.  Export schematics properly.  There are many gratuitous wiggles and nets crossing for no reason, to the point that it's confusing.  Then there is also lots of text overlapping other things.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you analyse it but as far as I'm concerned you've got a series tuned resonant circuit on the op-amp output to ground: -

[image]

And that is asking for trouble - you could replace the inductor with a resistor but then comes the next problem; C10, C11, C12, C13 and C14 are in effect a load capacitance on the op-amp output of about 10 nF.

What should you expect? Perfection doesn't occur in hardly any measure on an op-amp output and you can't expect stability with this on the output - the op-amp is being asked the equivalent of a motor scotter to tow a juggernaut.

I'm aware the LT1210 is a bit of a beast but you need some hint of loading that involves a resistor - try 10 ohm in series exclusively with C10.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that it was due to load capacitance but I miscalculated how much load capacitance there was. LT1210 has compensation and the oscillations stopped when I tweaked the feedback resistors to match the 10nF load capacitance.